# Ho to run vstest under specific account from VSTS?

Tags: authentication, mstest, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, vstest

We are running selenium E2E tests as part of VSTS Release. We're using Visual Studio Test task which runs vstest.console.exe as a `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` user. How can we specify a different account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this could not be achieved for now. Please take a look at this thread: [Test agent, Test Controller and MSTEST FAQ](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vstsqualitytools/2010/10/24/test-agent-test-controller-and-mstest-faq/) (Qustion 21), it should be also applied to VS test.

> ***Will Test Agents allow you to impersonate another user? Or does the
>   Test Agent always kick of tests as the user its configured start up
>   as?***
>
> There is no built in support for impersonation, so by default tests
>   run under the identity of the test agent. If this is something you
>   really need, you could write a unit test extension that does the
>   impersonation for you.

We could not specify the user in the "Visual Studio Test" step, the test will running with the agent.

As a workaround, you can try to change the agent service account to the specific account of the user. Or just deploy a new agent to run with the specific account, a sample for your reference : [Running Unit Tests on different machine during TFS 2015 build](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2016/06/04/running-unit-tests-on-different-machine-during-tfs-2015-build/)